# Setting values in matrix based on values in vector

Tags: matlab, matrix

If I have a 3 x 3 matrix called tmp and vector data such that

```
tmp = [1,0,0;2,0,0;3,0,0];
data = [1,3];
data = transpose(data);
```

In every row whose first element matches an element in data, I want to update that value in the second column to 1. This would result in tmp looking like this:

```
tmp = [1,1,0;2,0,0;3,1,0];
```

Is there a way I can do this without a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
tmp(:,2) = ismember(tmp(:,1),data)
```

Results:

```
tmp =

     1     1     0
     2     0     0
     3     1     0
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have really only two elements in data, this would do the trick :

```
tmp(:,2)=or(tmp(:,1)==data(1),tmp(:,1)==data(2))
```